# JPA bidirectional one-to-many and nulling child reference on remove from collection

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a bidirectional one-to-many master-detail table and I'm looking for a way to null the master-reference in a detail when that detail is removed from the masters collection of details. Orphan removal would probably work but I'm not looking to kill the detail since it has a life on it's own and might be associated with another master later on.

Is there any way to map this or does it involve manual fiddling e.g. loading the entity tree again, removing the detail-to-be-deleted so that some collection-proxy notices this and persisting?

Say I have
Master1 with a detail-collection of [Detail1, Detail2, Detail3]

If I in the UI remove Detail2, I'd like JPA to detect this so that on merge Detail2:s Master-reference would be nulled (so it might e.g. later be associated with Master2:s collection)

Sigh, been a while since I've fiddled with JPA.

Thankful for pointers,
Nik

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring orphan removal as you want detail to have a life outside of master and presuming you have a bidirectional relationship as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Master {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "master")
    private List<Detail> details = new ArrayList<>();
...
@Entity
public class Detail {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Master master;
...
```

You could fetch the detail by id and set master to null to dissociate it

```
@Transactional
public void removeFromMaster(Long detailId) {
    Detail detail = em.find(Detail.class, detailId);
    if (detail != null) {
        detail.setMaster(null);
    }
}
```